# Run CLI command when event triggers

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've created an Event Subscriber which looks at the `ThemeConfigChangedEvent`. This is all working fine. The next step is to run a CLI command when the event triggers.

I'm using `Symfony\Component\Process\Process` to process a new instance and run the command. But I've got an exception that the `bin/console` command is not found. Which is true, because I saw the code is executed in the public directory.

What's the best way to run the command from the root directory?

EDIT

Now I'm just moving a level up to the root directory like this:

```
$directory = '../';
chdir($directory);
```

Is this the way or is there an better solution to run the CLI command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the parameter `kernel.project_dir`.

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Subscriber\MySubscriber">
    <argument>%kernel.project_dir%</argument>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
public function __construct(string $projectDir)
{
    $this->consolePath = implode(\DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [$projectDir, 'bin', 'console']);
}
```